# Weird Android 4.1/4.2 WebView blurry and z-index error after turn on Hardware Acceleration

Tags: android, webview, html5-canvas, video-streaming, hardware-acceleration

I was using a Android WebView to migrate my HTML5 game into Android.
Android 5, 4.4.x and 4.3 work perfectly well, but 4.1/4.2 produced a very weird problem.

The game is a combination of video, canvas and other DOM elements.

In 4.1/4.2, there are two state:

1. everything fine, no problem
2. all canvas elements ignore z-index and always on the top of the page. video is the same but lower than all canvas elements. Every other DOM elements become very blurry

I found that the second state will be triggered only when Hardware Acceleration turn on and:

1. Show a modal box that on the top of the page
2. or Video played successfully (which is a HLS video stream)
3. or Display too many elements on the screen (I was using transform: scale to make the app fit the size of the screen, if I translate 3/4 elements out of the screen, the bug will be fixed)

I know this bug can be fixed if I turn off the Hardware Acceleration, but I am not allow to do that. Anyone could help?

Do I have a option to turn off Hardware Acceleration via CSS/JavaScript?

Or, any work around to fix this bug?

Tested Devices: 4.2 Galaxy S4, 4.2 HW NOTE 1W

Answer (score 0):

try using the translateZ to control simulate the z-index:

```
canvas{
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-1px);
}
otherDiv{
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
}
```